# LinkedIn OAuth redirect login returning "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, playframework, cors

I'm currently implementing OAuth login with LinkedIn in my React and Play app and am running into a CORS error when trying to redirect to the authorization page in my dev environment:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_i…basicprofile&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fusers%2Flinkedin. Redirect from 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_i…basicprofile&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fusers%2Flinkedin' to 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=%2Foauth%2Fv2%2Flogin-s…' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have the following setup:

- Play server running at localhost:9000
- React app (created via create-react-app) running at localhost:3000

My JS code calls the `/auth/linkedin` endpoint which is implemented as follows:

```
Action { implicit req: RequestHeader =>
  val csrfToken = CSRF.getToken.get.value
  Redirect(linkedinUrl(oauthConfig.linkedinClientId, csrfToken)).withSession("state" -> csrfToken)
}
```

I have my Play application set to handle CORS appropriately.

My react app just makes a request to the above endpoint via Axios:

`axios.get('/auth/linkedin')`

This responds with a 303 with a redirect to the LinkedIn auth page which then gives me the error.

How do I get the CORS policy working correctly in this dev setup?  I've tried adding the following to my package.json as the create-react-app documentation recommends:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:9000",`

And I've also tried setting a request header to `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"` on the redirect in the Play server with no success.

Note that going to localhost:9000/auth/linkedin redirects properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization` responses apparently don’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, and because they do not, your browser blocks your frontend JavaScript code from accessing the responses.

There are no changes you can make to your own frontend JavaScript code nor backend config settings that’ll allow your frontend JavaScript code to make requests the way you’re trying directly to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization` and get responses back.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS explains in more detail but the gist of it is: for CORS, the server the request is being sent to must be configured to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, nor your own backend server.

---

**2019-05-30 update**

The current state of things seems to be that when needing to do LinkedIn authorization, you’ll have to initiate the request from your backend code. There’s no way you can do it from your frontend code, because LinkedIn no longer provides any support for it at all.

LinkedIn did previously provide some support for handling it from frontend code. But the page that documented it, https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk, now has this:

> The JavaScript SDK is not currently supported

And https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates has this:

> Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps.

So the remainder of this answer (from 2017-06-13) has now become obsolete. But it’s preserved below for the sake of keeping the history complete.

---

**2017-06-13 details, now obsoleted**

Anyway https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk has official docs that explain how to request authorization for a user cross-origin, which appears to be just this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   [API_KEY]
    onLoad:    [ONLOAD]
    authorize: [AUTHORIZE]
    lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]

IN.User.authorize(callbackFunction, callbackScope);
</script>
```

And https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin has docs for another auth flow:

```
<script type="in/Login"></script> <!-- Create the "Sign In with LinkedIn" button-->

<!-- Handle async authentication & retrieve basic member data -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information!  Curiously if I just do something like `<a href="http://localhost:9000/auth/linkedin">Linkedin</a>` clicking the link works just fine, any idea why would that work while making the request via axios fails?  I think just doing a link might be the easiest for me.

Comment: When you click on the link that creates a *navigation*, which is very different than making a request from frontend JavaScript code and consuming the response. Browsers don’t block navigations cross-origin (otherwise the entire web wouldn’t work…)—but browsers do prevent frontend JavaScript code from being able to get responses from cross-origin requests unless the site/server the request is sent to indicates it is opting-in to receiving such requests. And the way that servers opt in to receiving cross-origin requests is, they include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in their responses

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks alot dude, You saved my time. Almost am running on same with google oauth, I tried all possible ways but no luck! Finally your comment solved my problem. Instead of calling a api call i jus t make it as a anchor tag, it's working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy I'm facing the same issue with Google Auth. Can you tell me how you solved it? I can't find where to change to an anchor tag

Comment: LinkedIn has stopped the support for JavaScript SDK https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk

Comment: @KamleshKarwande Thanks much for the heads-up — I’ve added an update to the answer

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem, so let's divide this problem into detailed steps

1. Hit request to get the code(from frontend)
2. now send this code to the backend
3. In the backend, make another call to LinkedIn OAuth API and get the access token
4. With this access token make 3 separate calls to get the name, profile picture
   and email of the user(yes you heard that right you need to make 3 separate calls and also the response JSON format is not very appealing)

[Visit this](https://www.wellhow.online/2021/04/setting-up-linkedin-oauth-and-fixing.html) for the detailed step-by-step process, it involves a lot of things. I can just share the process here but for the actual implementation [visit this.](https://www.wellhow.online/2021/04/setting-up-linkedin-oauth-and-fixing.html)

https://www.wellhow.online/2021/04/setting-up-linkedin-oauth-and-fixing.html

Answer (score -1):

What could be done is:

```
window.location.href='http://localhost:9000/auth/linkedin'
```

The `urlEndPoint` could be directly to linkedIn's API or a back-end service which makes the call to linkedIn's API.