# Vue.js + Google OAuth2 + Client-side rendering

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, vue.js, passport.js

I am implementing a log-in functionality in my web application. In order to do so, I am using a popular module called "passport" to do OAuth handling. Here is the problem!

My Signin.vue file:

```
<div>
    <div id="Navbar">
        <navigation-bar/>
    </div>

    <div id="contents">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-inner">
                <img src="../assets/logo.png" class="logo">
                <div class="user-input">
                    <div class="third-party-sign-in">
                        <a v-on:click.prevent="googleSigninRequest()"><div class="login-submit google-signin"><span class="helper"></span>Sign in with Google</div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
export default {
name: "SignIn",
methods: {
    googleSigninRequest: function() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/auth/google')
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}
```

OAuth is handled in auth-routes.js in server side as such:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
    clientID: secrets.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: secrets.googleClientSecret,
}, function (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

   })
);
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope:['profile']
}));
```

but it errors as such [image]

So I thought it was CORS issue on my side and tried to add a middleware that sets the header of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" field to "*". But the same error still persists. So according to this post:

[Oauth Redirect Returning No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530615/oauth-redirect-returning-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-t)

I realized that maybe Google does not allow CORS themselves. As far as I know, the receiver(Google) has to allow CORS.

Also, even if Google OAuth request succeeds in back-end, how does front-end know what or how to proc the "login" pop-up by Google...

So some people do this https://jsfiddle.net/phanan/a4qyysrh/ to handle the login on the client-side. But I want to do all of the logins of my webapp including Facebook and Linkedin in the back-end, and I just think doing the sign-in client-side in my case may not be the most optimal thing.

What should I do?? How should I handle Google OAuth signin using Vue.js? Maybe the approach I am taking, which is hosting front-end at one port and use AJAX request to back-end at a different port whenever I want to do something complex is not common?

Should I abandon Vue.js altogether and do server-side rendering using ejs or something? Help me please T.T !!

Comment: did you setup your google auth domains?

Comment: I did not, but as far as I know, passport's Google Strategy sets that up for me? Am I wrong?