# Redirecting for social login gives Cross Origin (Access control allow origin ) error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have developed a, web API using the ASP.NET CORE 2.0 for linkedin social plugin , which uses OAuth 2.0 for getting access_token . This works fine when testing it chrome browser.

Now, I m trying to develop a Front End UI using HTML , Javascript and JQuery .
Here is the code  of JS http://localhost:3001

```
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Javascript Works")
    BindEvents();
});


function BindEvents(){
      $("button").click( function(){
        console.log("bindevents works ");
        var LinkedinUrl =$("input").val();
        //Get information of the person 
        var url = "http://localhost:52971/api/linkedin/auth";
        $.ajaxSetup({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            crossOrigin: true
          });
        $.getJSON(url, function (data, status) {
            console.log(("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status));
        });
    });
}
```

I have enabled the CORS in .net core 2.0 WEB API to allow any request for quick working but i'm considering it to restrict to known domains only.

The error I get is

Failed to load https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:52971/api/linkedin/callback&state=state@1&scope=r_basicprofile: Redirect from 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:52971/api/linkedin/callback&state=state@1&scope=r_basicprofile' to

'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: check [Oauth Redirect Returning No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resourc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530615/oauth-redirect-returning-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-t?rq=1)

Comment: windows.location.href=" https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:52971/api/linkedin/callback&state=state@1&scope=r_basicprofile" , worked for me .