# CORS Error: LinkedIn Authentication; .NET Core 5 REST Api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-web-api, rest, linkedin-api

**Technology Stack**

- Using .NET CORE React Template
- 1 IIS Website
- Application Pool (v4 Integrated)
- Port 80

1. Clicking on a Register Button, calls the Register Component.
2. Component within a useEffect(), calls "/login URL using Axios
3. C# Map("/login") is called a Challenge to Authenticate using LinkedIn
4. The CORS Error is then returned

**Error**     [Snapshot 1 of 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gadDQ.png)
[Snapshot 2 of 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8HBB.png); [Snapshot 3 of 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbjfG.png);  [Snapshot 4 of 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45MWZ.png);  [Snapshot 5 of 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejhVG.png)

**React Code**

```
      const url = `/login`;

      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      }

      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
        headers: headers
      })
        .then((response) => {...})
        .catch((error: Error | AxiosError) => {...});
```

**C# Code - Linked Authentication, Cookies, CORS Middleware**

**Start.cs** - *ConfigureServices()*

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            #region AddAuthentication, AddLinkedIn, AddCookie
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddLinkedIn(o =>
                {
                    IConfigurationSection linkedinAuthNSection = 
                        Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Linkedin");

                    o.ClientId = linkedinAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                    o.ClientSecret = linkedinAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
                })
                .AddCookie(o =>
                {
                    o.LoginPath = "/login";
                    o.LogoutPath = "/logout";
                });
            #endregion

            #region Global CORS Policy Declaration
            services.AddCors(o =>
            {
                o.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                );
            });
            #endregion 

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "client-app/build";
            });
        }
```

**Start.cs** - *Configure()*

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            #region Map/login
            app.Map("/login", builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" };

                    await context.ChallengeAsync("LinkedIn", properties);
                });
            });
            #endregion

            #region Map/logout
            app.Map("/logout", builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    await context.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                    context.Response.Redirect("/");
                });
            });
            #endregion

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = Path.Join(env.ContentRootPath, "client-app");

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(240);
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: ★ I think what is missing is how to link the attribute *[EnableCors]* to that of the following Path:
`app.Map("/login", builder =>
            {
                MapLogin(builder);
            });`

Comment: What exactly *is* the cors error? cors errors are quite direct and accurate in noting what is wrong

Comment: @KevinB In the Dev Tools, it just shows CORS in the Network Tab

(1). A React Application, defined as a "Website" in IIS with Port 80.
(2) A .NET Core REST API is defined as an "Application" within the above "Website" , at a different physical location.
(3) The React issues a "login" request to the REST API.
(4) The "/login" request issues an Authentication challenge to LinkedIn.
(5) I then receive a CORS error

Comment: What browser are you using that gives such little information?

Comment: You should put the text of the error in your question. You are getting down voted because it isn't there. Google links to questions based on the text in them and you linking to generate an error is completely ephemeral since it will be gone if it gets fixed. There are other minor things but that is the big one. Your title isn't helpful either and should be edited to reflect the error message too. 

How to ask a question - > https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Rodger The following is my first line in the post *I get the CORS error the link below.

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSubscriberRESTApiUrlBFF%2Fsignin-linkedin
*

Comment: @Rodger I tried to depict the error and context in the title, hence followed the guidelines but would appreciate any further suggestions for a change.

Comment: @KevinB Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Your dev console should be giving a much more long-winded error message, if it's a cors error.

Comment: @KevinB, I have done some updates according to your questions

Comment: @Rodger I have done some updates according to your suggstions

Comment: The CORS error isn't important, it appears as though you aren't properly implementing Linkedin's authentication process.

Comment: @KevinB Many Thanks! Would you be able to advise me where I'm getting it all wrong, please and how I should be doing it too, please. Many thanks in advance

Comment: No, unfortunately, that's not an authentication process i wish to investigate

Comment: @KevinB, ok, could you suggest the alternative then, please? I'm really desperate and struggling for 3 weeks now.

Comment: @KevinB, is my working solution perhaps in line with your one, please?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it working!

I have made 2 major changes, after trying to fathom, understand internalizing. Thanks to the yellow warning symbols ⚠ of Chrome Dev Tools, that let me to [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/oauth-2-0-with-github-in-asp-net-core/) and change 1 of the solution.

**Change 1**

- Applied the major snippets of the above example code to my React SPA .NET Core project
- Dropped the Map Middleware (*app.Map("/login"*) that allows branching of the pipeline path.
- In favor for a .NET Controller/Action.
- However more specifically, just Action since the *"/login"* is added to the path, of the URL, which makes it difficult to accept the successful sign-in.

**Change 2**

- Dropped Axios call only for the Authentication UI Interaction, since LinkedIn, does not support it. [LinkedIn OAuth redirect login returning "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530615/linkedin-oauth-redirect-login-returning-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)
- In favour of using HTML href.

**Authentication.cs**

```
    //[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register(string authType = "LinkedIn")
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string authType = "LinkedIn")
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Logout()
        {
            return SignOut();
        }
```

**Start.cs** *ConfigureServices()*

```
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = "LinkedIn";
            })
               .AddCookie()
               .AddOAuth("LinkedIn", o =>
               {
                   o.CorrelationCookie.HttpOnly = true;
                   o.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                   
                   var linkedInSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:LinkedIn");

                   o.ClientId = linkedInSection.GetSection("ClientId").Get<string>();
                   o.ClientSecret = linkedInSection.GetSection("ClientSecret").Get<string>();
                   o.CallbackPath = new PathString(linkedInSection.GetSection("CallbackPath").Get<string>());

                   o.AuthorizationEndpoint = linkedInSection.GetSection("AuthorizationEndpoint").Get<string>();
                   o.TokenEndpoint = linkedInSection.GetSection("TokenEndpoint").Get<string>();
                   o.UserInformationEndpoint = linkedInSection.GetSection("UserInformationEndpoint").Get<string>();

                   o.Scope.Add("r_liteprofile");
                   o.Scope.Add("r_liteprofile");

                   o.Events = new OAuthEvents
                   {
                       OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                       {
                           var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                           request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                           request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                           var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                           var json = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                           context.RunClaimActions(json.RootElement);
                       }
                   };
               });
        }
```

**Start.cs** *Configure()*

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Chrome browser, try installing an extension called **Access control Allow Origin** from the Chrome web store . And Open the Options or settings page of that extension and type your localhost address in the textbox like this : *https://localhost:80* in ur case

I had faced this issue once and this extension worked for me..

Comment: installing a browser extension is a pretty awful way of solving a cors error.

Comment: @igmani Not sure we want to go that route since we can't force our clients to follow that process